# Which Function in Matlab Should I use to Validate a Model forecast() or predict()?

Tags: matlab

I have used two types of models for modeling a SISO system with a time series data. The first is ARIMAx and the second one the Output-Error. Now, I should know which of the two performs best in forecasting the output giving the input in certain horizon, 15 days in my case, and only the necessary observed outputs for the model initialize properly. In `Matlab`, it is presented two functions in that seems to be used to validate models the `forecast()` and `predict()`. I have been reading the difference between predicting and forecasting and apparently people misconfuse a lot the two terms. I would like to know which of the two I should use to validate a model and choose the best one. The main point is that I have to test the model's performance for many horizons. In other words, how the model performs to forecast on the first day ahead, on the second day ahead until the 15th day ahead. I wrote the following code as an example:

```
close all
clear all
tic;
uhe = {'furnas'};

% Set the structures to be evaluated in ARMAx model
na = 10;
nb = 2;
nc = 1;
nk = 2;

% Set the structures to be evaluated in OE model
nbb = 10;
nf = 6;
nkk = 0;

u = 1;

% Read  training dataset file and set iddata definitions
data_train = importdata(strcat('train_',uhe{u},'.dat'));
data_test = importdata(strcat('test_',uhe{u},'.txt'));
data_valid = importdata(strcat('valid_',uhe{u},'.txt'));
data_complet = vertcat(data_train, data_valid, data_test);

data_complet = iddata(data_complet(:,2),data_complet(:,1));
data_complet.TimeUnit = 'days';
data_complet.InputName = 'Chuva';
data_complet.OutputName = 'Vazão';
data_complet.InputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_complet.OutputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_complet.Name = 'Sistema Chuva-Vazão';

data_train = iddata(data_train(:,2),data_train(:,1));
data_train.TimeUnit = 'days';
data_train.InputName = 'Chuva';
data_train.OutputName = 'Vazão';
data_train.InputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_train.OutputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_train.Name = 'Sistema Chuva-Vazão';

data_valid = iddata(data_valid(:,2),data_valid(:,1));
data_valid.TimeUnit = 'days';
data_valid.InputName = 'Chuva';
data_valid.OutputName = 'Vazão';
data_valid.InputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_valid.OutputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_valid.Name = 'Sistema Chuva-Vazão';

data_test = iddata(data_test(:,2),data_test(:,1));
data_test.TimeUnit = 'days';
data_test.InputName = 'Chuva';
data_test.OutputName = 'Vazão';
data_test.InputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_test.OutputUnit = 'm³/s';
data_test.Name = 'Sistema Chuva-Vazão';

% Modeling training dataset with ARMAx
models_train_armax = armax(data_train,[na nb nc nk]);

% Modeling training dataset with OE
models_train_oe = oe(data_train,[nbb nf nkk]);

% Evalutaing the validation dataset ARMAX
x0 = findstates(models_train_armax,data_valid);
OPT = simOptions('InitialCondition',x0); 
ssmodel_armax=idss(models_train_armax); 
models_valid_armax = sim(ssmodel_armax,data_valid,OPT);

% Evaluating the validation dataset OE
x0 = findstates(models_train_oe,data_valid);
OPT = simOptions('InitialCondition',x0); 
ssmodel_oe=idss(models_train_oe); 
models_valid_oe = sim(ssmodel_oe,data_valid,OPT);

% Predicting Horizon
hz = 20;

% Applying predict function
opt = predictOptions('InitialCondition','e');
[y_armax_pred] = predict(ssmodel_armax,data_valid(1:end),hz,opt);
[y_oe_pred] = predict(ssmodel_oe,data_valid(1:end),hz,opt);

% Applying forecast function
opt = forecastOptions('InitialCondition','e');
[y_armax_fc] = forecast(ssmodel_armax,data_train((end-max([na nb nc nk])):end),hz,data_test.u(1:hz),opt);
[y_oe_fc] = forecast(ssmodel_oe,data_train((end-max([nbb nf nkk])):end),hz,data_test(1:hz),opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you are trying to validate the model. Generally you would use the `predict` command as you would want backtest against previous data.

Alternatively you could use `forecast` if you have a cross-validation/holdout sample and you would like to test against that

Matlab's [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/forecast.html) has an interesting line regarding the difference between forecast and predict

> forecast performs prediction into the future, in a time range beyond the last instant of measured data. In contrast, the predict command predicts the response of an identified model over the time span of measured data. Use predict to determine if the predicted result matches the observed response of an estimated model. If sys is a good prediction model, consider using it with forecast.

Also note that Matlab's [help for predict](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/predict.html)  also says that careful model validation should not use the default value of the prediction horizon.

> For careful model validation, a one-step-ahead prediction (K = 1) is usually not a good test for validating the model sys over the time span of measured data. Even the trivial one step-ahead predictor, y(hat)(t)=y(t−1),  can give good predictions. So a poor model may look fine for one-step-ahead prediction of data that has a small sample time. Prediction with K = Inf, which is the same as performing simulation with sim command, can lead to diverging outputs because low-frequency disturbances in the data are emphasized, especially for models with integration. Use a K value between 1 and Inf to capture the mid-frequency behavior of the measured data.